# I'm trying to figure out why this is constantly repeating instead of repeating at the specified amount of time in the line repeat

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to create a code that creates random amount of a cactus in random locations which is made up of several lines. However it seems like it is infinitely creating itself in random areas. And I was wondering why my repeat code doesn't actually repeat the specific amount?

My code:

```js
function setup() {
   createCanvas (windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
function draw() {

   repeat(1, cactus);

}

function cactus(){
   const x = randomNumber (0,windowWidth);
   const y = randomNumber (0, windowHeight);

   line (x + 300, y + 275, x + 300, y + 250); //main branch


   line (x + 300, y + 258, x + 308, y + 258); //right branch1 
   line (x + 308, y + 258, x + 308, y + 254); //right branch2

   line (x + 300, y + 265, x + 295, y + 265); //right branch1 
   line (x + 295, y + 265, x + 295, y + 255); //right branch2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function draw() is a loop and therefore repeats several times a second; drawing the cacti here will cause a very large number to be drawn.  If you want to control the number being drawn it will be better to do that outside of function draw(); function setup() would be a good alternative.  I was unable to get 'repeat()' to work in the p5.js WebEditor in Chrome so I left it out of the following demo:

```
var numCacti = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  background(209);
  for(let i = 0; i < numCacti; i++){
    cactus();
  }
}

function draw() {
}

function cactus(){
  const x = random(0, 400);
  const y = random(0, 200);

  line(x + 300, y + 275, x + 300, y + 250);
  
  line(x + 300, y + 258, x + 308, y + 258);  
  line(x + 308, y + 258, x + 308, y + 254);
  
  line(x + 300, y + 265, x + 295, y + 265);
  line(x + 295, y + 265, x + 295, y + 255);
  
}
```

Comment: You got a +1 for using the correct plural of cactus (and for manually typing the code that the OP published as an image)